# iPod Touch Second Generation - firmware

Tags: iphone, ios, ipod

I am updating an app that initially was compatible with iOS 2.0 and up.

As Apple dropped support for releases < 3.0, I am being forced to drop support for 2.0.

Some beta testers using iPod Touch second generation are complaining the software is not running well. These guys report their iPod Touch 2nd Gen to be model A1228.
The app runs perfectly on iPhone 3G, 3GS and 4.

The app does not use any function that is not present on iPod Touch 2nd gen.

I suppose it can be a firmware problem on the iPod Touch 2nd Gen. The guys may be using an old release or never updated.

My question is: what firmware version came with iPod Touch 2nd gen and what is the latest firmware version available for this device? 3.1.3?

thanks.

Comment: Probably "not running well" simply means "too slow" or "uses too much memory".

Comment: no. Some images and buttons are not showing on their devices. The memory footprint of this app is the lowest ever. Just under 1 megabyte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the first firmware was, but you can get iOS 4.1 for iPod touch 2nd genereation, and if you are a developer, iOS 4.2 as well.

You can get information about the device using the [UIDevice](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html) class. To get the version information, use the `systemVersion` property, which will return a NSString.

**EDIT:**

According to [this website](http://www.felixbruns.de/iPod/firmware/), the first iOS version was 2.1.1. You can also download all of the iOS firmwares there.

Comment: thanks, but Apple site says iOS 4.1 is just compatible with 3G, 3GS and 4. Check it out here: http://www.apple.com/iphone/software-update/

Comment: ah, I found another page that says it is compatible: http://www.apple.com/ipodtouch/software-update/